# Markdown files starting with '##' confuse KDE

Tags: arch-linux, kde, file-association, markdown, xdg

I have an unusual problem with KDE in Arch Linux. In particular, Dolphin detects files with the `.md` file extension as  MATLAB rather than Markdown files, but only when the file's first two characters are `##` (yes, really).

Here is a simple test I did from the shell:

```
[jason@jasons-laptop Desktop]$ xdg-mime query filetype test-1.md
text/x-matlab
[jason@jasons-laptop Desktop]$ cat test-1.md
## test
[jason@jasons-laptop Desktop]$ xdg-mime query filetype test-2.md
text/markdown
[jason@jasons-laptop Desktop]$ cat test-2.md
Test
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this bug, or how to fix it? I've tried using `update-mime-database`, but it doesn't seem to help. I would consider filing a bug report, but I'm not really sure what program is responsible.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out! I had to add the following lines to `~/.local/share/mime/packages/Override.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mime-info>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
        <mime-type type="text/markdown">
                <magic priority="50"><match value="##" type="string" offset="0"/></magic>
        </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

And then run `update-mime-database /home/[username]/.local/share/mime`.

I'm still not quite sure why `##` causes files to be detected as MATLAB by default.